# Multi module angular

Tags: angular

I would like to build an architecture for my angular project, but modular and with each component with unique responsibility.

So, in each component I have, html, css, component, service, model, dto and module.

I have a lot of doubt about the part of the modules I'm creating, because sometimes, I have the following error.

```
Type CarComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: CarModule and ComponentsModule! Please consider moving CarComponent to a higher module that imports CarModule and ComponentsModule. 
You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes CarComponent then import that NgModule in CarModule and ComponentsModule.


----|app
----|---|components
----|---|-------|business
----|---|-------|-----|cars
----|---|-------|-----|-----|model
----|---|-------|-----|-----|-- car-model.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-----|-- car-dto.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-----|service
----|---|-------|-----|-----|-- car.service.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-- car.component.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-- car.html
----|---|-------|-----|-- car.css
----|---|-------|-----|-- car.module.ts import/export car.component.ts
----|---|-------| business.module.ts // import/export car.module.ts
----|---|-------|shared
----|---|-------|-----| menu
----|---|-------|-----|-----|model
----|---|-------|-----|-----|-- menu-model.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-----|-- menu-dto.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-----|service
----|---|-------|-----|-----|-- menu.service.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-- menu.component.ts
----|---|-------|-----|-- menu.html
----|---|-------|-----|-- menu.css
----|---|-------|-----|-- menu.module.ts
----|---| components.module.ts
----| app.module.ts
```

Comment: This doesn't seem architecturally sound. Modules are containers for components and services. Having a module in a component is backwards. You should create your "business" module at the root, and generate components inside of a "components" directory inside of there, services inside of a "services" directory, etc

Comment: @p32094 I understand, with that I also have things separate. And for other modules for components, for example share.module that will import components from a shared folder. It would be the same thing

Comment: Putting a module inside of a component doesn't make it a child of that component. It's just making your file structure more confusing. Angular doesn't care where you put it. [I'd highly recommend you read this article](https://itnext.io/choosing-a-highly-scalable-folder-structure-in-angular-d987de65ec7)